# Cheap Improvement of Eigenvalue/Eigenvector for large positive-semi definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a large, dense, symmetric, positive semi-definite $n \times n$ Matrix $\mathcal{M}$, which is constructed by a slight perturbation of a Matrix $\mathcal{M'}$ (with an symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix). I have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathcal{M'}$ and I am wondering whether I can use them to (computationally) cheaply approximate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\mathcal{M}$ (So in practice I care about the constant costs of the algorithms).

I am currently doing a few iteration of the simultaneous iteration method:

$\mathcal{V}',R \gets QR(\mathcal{M} \cdot \mathcal{V})$

but this is probably less than ideal.

Comment: Have you tried perturbation theory? Write $M(\epsilon) = M' + \epsilon (M - M')$. Write the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M(\epsilon)$ as formal power series in $\epsilon$. You should be able to do at least a first order approximation cheaply. I do not think it will be more accurate than subspace iteration, but have a short look.

Comment: interesting idea, thanks!